# Azure AD B2C Azure Mobile Services Xamrin Forms Example

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

Looking for an example for Azure Mobile Services developed in Xamarin Forms that is authenticated through Azure AD B2C.  I have a working solution where I am able to authenticate using Azure B2C in Xamarin Forms but unable to use the resulting token in Azure Mobile Services. See code snippet below:

```
public static PublicClientApplication AuthenticationClient { get; private set; }
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(Constants.MobileServiceClientName);                  
result = App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(
                        Constants.Scopes,
                        string.Empty,
                        UIBehavior.SelectAccount,
                        string.Empty,
                        null,
                        Constants.Authority, null);
                    JObject objToken = new JObject();
objToken.Add("authenticationToken", result.IdToken);

//I am successfully able to get an Id token for Microsoft, Google and Twitter providers but when I use the token to login to my Azure Mobile Service app, I get a "Not Authorized" error

MobileServiceUser user = await MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount, objToken);
```

Any and all ideas are appreciated.

Comment: See code changes to the above:

Comment: See code changes to the above:  objToken.Add("authenticationToken", result.IdToken); has been changed to objToken.Add("access_token", result.IdToken) and I have changed MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount to MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzzureActiveDirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue.  The Azure AD Provider configuration on my Azure Mobile App was not configured correctly.

Here is the corrected code:

```
public static PublicClientApplication AuthenticationClient { get; private set; }
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(Constants.MobileServiceClientName);                  
result = App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(
                        Constants.Scopes,
                        string.Empty,
                        UIBehavior.SelectAccount,
                        string.Empty,
                        null,
                        Constants.Authority, null);
                    JObject objToken = new JObject();
objToken.Add("access_token", result.IdToken);

//I am successfully able to get an Id token for Microsoft, Google and Twitter providers but when I use the token to login to my Azure Mobile Service app, I get a "Not Authorized" error

MobileServiceUser user = await MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, objToken);
```

I can provide more details on the Azure AD configuration if anyone is interested.  So now, I have a fully working Xamarin Forms Azure Mobile App that is authenticated using Azure AD B2C and so far works with Microsoft, Google and Twitter providers.

Comment: I'm interested, if you could share more details that'd be appreciated.  I've got XF working with Azure AD B2C authentication complete with MVC / mobile backend; However, I always get "Not Authorized" when accessing a secure Table Controller from the mobile app.